# Is "in the essence of time" legitimate? Standard? Regional?

Tags: american-english, malapropisms, southern-white-vernacular-english

I had never heard "in the essence of time" before a recent trip to Virginia. Various local attendees of a meeting I attended used the phrase to justify moving on to a new topic, in a situation where I would expect to hear "in the interest of time."

Comment: Malaphor:  perfect explanation.  {thumbs up}

Comment: It does not sound odd to me, but I probably use "in the interest of" or "for time's sake" more. "Time is of the essence" appears to have origins as a legal term, and in the South we do have a tendency to use older phrasings.  Flip it around for the malaphor, and you've answered your own question.

Comment: People speak "all screwed up". They truncate, they switch topics, they do all sorts of things, and they especially turn expressions on their heads [haha].  **"time is of the essence**" is used in legal language, which has sort of migrated out into the world. This is clearly a bungling attempt to use it. It's actually pretty funny. I will have to remember it. "In the essence of time", let's move on. This is like people using "verbiage" incorrectly to mean the text in a blurb or article. And now, they all seem to say: verbage. :)

Answer (score 1):

It strikes my ear as a malapropism, and I agree with the theory I found (the first Google result when searching the phrase in quotation marks):

> This subtle malaphor is a mix of “in the interest of saving time” (in order to save time) and “time is of the essence” (meeting the deadlines is essential).
>
> <sub>https://malaphors.com/2013/09/17/in-the-essence-of-time/</sub>

That said, language is certainly known to evolve, and there may be more happening here than I recognize. I'd be interested in a more detailed explanation, especially if someone has a reasoned argument for this phrase being useful, meaningful, or in wider use than I'm aware.

Comment: How is "essence of time" an evolution? It just poor imagery. They are trying to say: as time is of the essence, etc.